# How to use AJAX on rails to Update thumb_up numbers?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to use AJAX to update the thump up number 
but I do not know how completely.

**View document**

```
<% for article in @articles %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 location">
      <a href="#"><img src="<%= article.pic_url %>" class="img-responsive img-rounded location_img"></a>

      <div class="info_box">
        <p class="title"><%= article.title %></p>

        <p class="author">作者: <span><%= article.author %></span></p>

        <p class="summary"><%= article.content_about %></p>

        <p class="link"><a href="/article/show?fid=<%= article.id %>">more...</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-up">
        <a href="/article/like_it?fid=<%= article.id %>"><img src="/IMAGE/thumb.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
        <p>+<%= article.like_number %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
 def like_it
 fid = params[:fid]
 fid = params[:id] if (fid.blank?)
 @article = Article.find fid

 @article.like_number +=1
 @article.save

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to("/article/location_go") }
   format.xml { head :ok }
 end  

 end
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit this question to reflect the tips in the link. For starters, code cannot be in images, and needs to be in the post itself using code tags.

Comment: Thank you very much.~I have edited~

Comment: Where is your javascript code? Have you even attempted the AJAX yet?

Comment: I don't konw how....sorry   I need some example.